# Parsing avconv/ffmpeg rawvideo output?

Tags: c++, stream, ffmpeg

I'm about to begin a project that will involve working with the output of avconv/ffmpeg, pixel-by-pixel, in rgb32 format. I intend to work with a raw byte stream, such as from the `pipe` protocol. Basic pointer arithmetic (C/C++) will be used to iterate over these pixels, and modify them in arbitrary manners in real-time.

I've created a very small file using rawvideo format and codec, and opened it up in a hex editor. As expected, it's just a series of pixels, read right to left, top to bottom. No distinguishing between lines - no problem, if you know how wide the video is beforehand. No distinguishing between frames - no problem, if you also know how tall the video is. No file header for frame rate, or even what the encoding (rgb32, rgb24, yuv, etc.) is - again, as long as you already know, it can be worked with.

The problem occurs when - for one reason or another - some bytes are missing. Maybe the stream isn't being examined from the beginning, which is likely be the case in my project, or maybe something just got lost. All the pre-existing knowledge in the world (besides maybe a byte count of what's been missed, not gonna happen) won't prevent it from happily chugging along, with an incorrect offset of line and frame.

So, what I'm looking for is an option for rawvideo, or possibly some other format/codec, that will allow me to work with the resulting stream at the pixel level, in RGB, yet still have a clear definition of where a new frame begins, even if it happens to start "looking" in the middle of a frame. (Width, height, and framerate will indeed be known.)

Comment: Welcome to the world of containers. That's what they were written for :) Might be possible to simply wrap the raw stream in an AVI container where you could read from chunk to chunk. (Then again I don't know whether AVI chunks always have to start at full frames.) The AVI would also store pixel dimensions and frame rate. The question is whether you could modify the encoder in such a way that it'd explicitly signal a frame start with a certain bitcode.